# How to map with join by RDD Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reduce

I have a list of (id-(name-value) pairs. Such like this

```scala
val input =  sc.parallelize(Array(Array(1, "a 10"),
                                  Array(1, "b 11"), 
                                  Array(3, "a 12"),
                                  Array(3, "b 13"),
                                  Array(3, "c 14"),
                                  Array(4, "b 15")))
```

The map phase has key is the id and value is (name-value) string.

```scala
val rdd = input.map(x => (x(0), x(1)))
```

My expected result is: for each id, compare values around based by name with a f() function.

For example, with id == "3", we got result after reduce phase:

```
(key: ab, value: f(12,13))
(key: ac, value: f(12,14))
(key: bc, value: f(13,14))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDD can be joined with himself for get all pairs, and only required row can be left by filtering:

```
// split string value on two parts
val rdd = input.map(x => (x(0), x(1).toString.split(" ")))
  .map({ case (key, parts) => (key, (parts(0), parts(1))) })

// join , filter, and transform to expected
val both = rdd
  .join(rdd)
  .filter({ case (_, (v1, v2)) => v1._1 < v2._1 })
  .map({ case (key, (v1, v2)) => (s"[$key] key: " + v1._1 + v2._1, s"value: f(${v1._2},${v2._2})") })
```

Output:

```
([1] key: ab,value: f(10,11))
([3] key: ab,value: f(12,13))
([3] key: ac,value: f(12,14))
([3] key: bc,value: f(13,14))
```

PS: advanced filtering can be used here.